# how to pass the an authenticated user to forms.py in django

Tags: django, authentication, django-forms

I have a django app with which every registered user can create categories. For the authentication I am using django-all-auth. My `models.py` looks like this:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    create_date = models.DateTimeField('date added', auto_now_add=True)
    modify_date = models.DateTimeField('date modified', default=timezone.now)

class Category(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    user = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    create_date = models.DateTimeField('date added', auto_now_add=True)
    modify_date = models.DateTimeField('date modified', default=timezone.now)
```

On the index page the user can see the created categories and create new ones. 
The views.py:

```
def CategoryView(request):
    user = 0
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        user = request.user
    form = CategoryNameForm()
    form.user = user
    context = {
        'categories': Category.objects.all(),
        'form': form,
        'user':user,
        }
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CategoryNameForm(request.POST)
        form.user = user
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
    return render(request, 'myapp/index.html',context)
```

forms.py:
    class CategoryNameForm(forms.ModelForm):

```
    class Meta:
        model = Category
        fields = ('name',)
```

The authentication works. So I was thinking to just put pass the user field into the form :

```
class CategoryNameForm(forms.ModelForm):

        class Meta:
            model = Category
            fields = ('name','user',)
```

hide it and then, just select it via JS since the user is in the context. I was just wondering if there is an easier way. This  `form.user = user` for some reason didn't work, I get a NOT NULL constraint failure

Comment: so you want to make sure just logged in users can access? how about `@login_required` in the view.py file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are couple of ways but here is one:

```
class CategoryNameForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Category
        fields = ('name',)  # take out user you don't need it here

    def save(self, **kwargs):
        user = kwargs.pop('user')
        instance = super(CategoryNameForm, self).save(**kwargs)
        instance.user = user
        instance.save()
        return instance
```

Then in view:

```
if form.is_valid():
    form.save(user=request.user, commit=False)
```

Make sure your `CategoryView` is only accessible by authenticated user. Otherwise you will still get NOT NULL constraint failure for user.

Comment: this worked, perfect thanks, I had to change this line though to `instance.user = Profile.objects.get(user=user)`

Comment: Yes correct, got confused by your naming convention :) P.S you can also do just `instance.user = user.profile`

Comment: it's pretty terrible, any advice where I could learn better naming conevntions?

Comment: You just need to think more :) You have ForeignKey to Profile but column name is user, doesn't make sense right? (unless you have a strong reason or need) `profile = models.ForeignKey(Profile)` makes more sense. For Python coding guidlines you can check [pep-8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) and to validate your files against some guidelines you can use [pycodestyle](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pycodestyle/1.8.0.dev0)